# Scrapy: yield form request prints none?

Tags: python, web, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am writing a spider to scrap website:

First url www.parenturl.com calls parse function, from there i have extracted url www.childurl.com which i have a callback to parse2 function and it returns dict.

Question 1) I need to store the dict value in mysql database with other 7 values which I have extracted from parent url in parse function ? (response_url prints none)

```
def parse(self, response):
    for i in range(0,2):
        url = response.xpath('//*[@id="response"]').extract()
        response_url=yield SplashFormRequest(url,method='GET',callback=self.parse2)
        print response_url # prints None

def parse2(self, response):
    dict = {'url': response.url}
    return dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the result of the second callback on the spider object and then printing it is not guaranteed to work because of scrapy's [asynchronous nature](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#event-driven-networking). Instead, you could try [passing additional data to callback functions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments), something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for i in range(0, 2):
        item = ...  # extract some information
        url = ...  # construct URL
        yield SplashFormRequest(url, callback=self.parse2, meta={'item': item})

def parse2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']  # get data from previous parsing method
    item.update({'key': 'value'})  # add more information
    print item  # do something with the "complete" item
    return item
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cannot equate a yield call to a variable because it acts like a return call.

Try removing it

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.results = []
    for i in range(0,2):
        url = response.xpath('//*[@id="response"]').extract()
        request = SplashFormRequest(url,method='GET',callback=self.parse2)
        yield request
    print self.results

def parse2(self, response):
    # print response here !
    dict = {'url': response.url}
    self.results.append(dict)
```

Comment: ok but where can i catch and print dict which is returned from parse2 function?

Comment: store it in the parse2 func. i.e. don't return it

Comment: But I have 7 values in parse function to be inserted in dB which I have extracted from parent url.

Comment: not sure on what you mean. Are you referring to your for loop ?

Comment: I am extracting other values in parse function...the code for that is not included..

Comment: oh. Make use of the self container. see updated solution

Comment: @spec "where can i catch and print dict which is returned from parse2 function?" If that's what you want to ask you'd better ask it in a question, not in a comment. Your question about `yield` has already been answered.